# How to properly use Regular Expressions in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I want to know how can I separate this string:

```
"Venda R$ 3.780.000,00  Aluguel  Condomínio R$ 1.980,00 IPTU R$ 7.990,00 Resumo de Custo"
```

so it can be like: 3780000, 1980 and 7990. I'm new on regular expressions, so a detailed explanation would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need a regex to match

- `[\d.]` digit or dot
- `[\d.]{3,}` more than 3 chars of that

Then remove the dot and convert to `int`

```
import re

values = "Venda R$ 3.780.000,00  Aluguel  Condomínio R$ 1.980,00 IPTU R$ 7.990,00 Resumo de Custo"
result = [int(x.replace(".", "")) for x in re.findall(r"[\d.]{3,}", values)]
print(result)  # [3780000, 1980, 7990]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the general framework, and then point out some issues.

You start by describing what you want in words.  You want a digit, followed by a collection of digits or comma or period, ending with a digit.  That's:

```
import re
srch = "Venda R$ 3.780.000,00  Aluguel Condominio R$ 1.980,00 IPTU R$ 7.990,00 Resumo de Custo"

f = re.findall( r"\d[0-9.,]*\d", srch )
print(f)
```

Which gives:

```
['3.780.000,00', '1.980,00', '7.990,00']
```

From there, is' up to you to convert that to numbers, by stripping the periods and dropping the cents, if you need to.